OpenModelica, imported FMU and FMPY, all three give different results
I have modelled a model in OpenModelica and exported the FMU from it. When I am testing the FMU file inside OpenModelica and inside FMPy, the output of the model is zero. When I am running the model inside OpenModelica get nonzero values (correct values). What could be problem ? I have ran both CS and ME with the same problems and the used FMI version is 2.
I am not allowed put the code here, so I did type pseudocode. Variables are totally different, but the functionality is correct.
With imported FMU and OpenModelica I might some values for the signal3, alas the signal3 is zero with FMPy.
I have spend about two days searching information
the summary is that
der()... might cause problems when it is exported as FMU
why when .... works as the imported FMU with OpenModelica and not with FMPy.
equation
  when signal1 >= 1 then
    signal2 = time;
 elsewhen signal1 < 1 then
    signal2 = 0;

signal3 = signal2+10;

if singal1 >= 1 and time > signal3 then
  signal4 = der(signal5);
else
  signal4 = 0;
end if;

I have tried CS and ME models to solve the problem

Please make your example a complete Modelica model by defining all variables and providing equations for all variables. The Modelica tool might solve the equations in a different way than you think.

Found the reason why PYFMI gave different results. I had custom_input.py from FMPY as the base for my code and it looks like that the model behaves differently with it.  I have not had time to fully understood why, but with simulate_fmu function it works correctly.
Der() causes still problems with FMU.
